# How can i trigger clicking of the "today" button by code?

Tags: fullcalendar

How can i trigger clicking of the "today" button by code in FullCalendar? If I where to this by an external button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/today/

Answer (score 6):

You have access to fullCalendar, so you can do something like this:

```
$('#external-button').on('click', function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without actually looking at the code, I would assume that the "Today" button is hooked to a JQuery or Javascript method within the FullCalendar code.  *Just call that method.*

Answer (score 0):

In case the [documentation URL](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/today/) posted above goes dead...

> Moves the calendar to the current date.

```
.fullCalendar( 'today' )
```

> Example using today with an external button:

```
$('#my-today-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
});
```